# migrating from wss3 to sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, migration, foundation

I have a question but not sure if I explain well because I do not even understand exactly what I need.
I need to migrate a sites (I do not know who they worked or how, this is on my job, I'm newbie there of course).

I started with this steps (https://win1337ist.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/exporting-and-importing-sites-between-wss-3-and-sharepoint-foundation-2010/=
)
but when I try to import that database, I can't because is too big.

We have an express version of 2010 where is allowed only cca 10 GB for database and ours is bigger of course.

We have that sharepoint on one server and I'm trying migrate websites with webdeployment tool from II6 to II7.

My question is, is it possible to migrate that database on server on which we have enough space(another one), and than on server where sites needs to be have just some link to that other server where database is and use that on this way ?!

Does this question even make sense or am I confused something. For even itself I do not know exactly what to do or some such thing in question.
Because, honestly have no idea about all this and at work I have to do.

Comment: yes, sharepoint can (basically) use any mssql database anywhere, as long as the appropriate permissions are set up for SP to access the db.

Comment: but, how I need to do this ?  I didn't find any tutorial for this :) and me alone not know how to do this..

Comment: sorry, but this isn't programming. this is database/server-admin stuff. you'd probably have more luck asking the db-specific stuff on the DBA site, and the sharepoint migration on the SP-specific site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/  http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you Marc. Programming is my domain also, because of that I dont understand any of this but on my work I must to investigate this how to do.  Thank you really.